# Excel: Change "," to "."

Tags: excel, period

Ever since i added a multiple language option for my computer, Excel decided to turn all my decimals into commas. I need to turn them back into decimals again. How do i do this with least amount of work? If you know an EASY way to do this, emphasis on easy, please tell. When it is converted, i need a number, not text or anything else. I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.

I tried the approach where you make this formula in Excel

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A4;",";".")+0
```

Which should, i'm assuming, get cell A4, change comma into period and then by adding 0 convert to number. My original number is 17.6, now i'm getting 41807.

Comment: you should change [PC regional settings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/08/16/how-to-change-regional-settings-for-all-users-on-a-computer.aspx)

Comment: or change decimal separator using VBA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're two options for you.

1) change [regional settings on your PC](http://www.nirvanatec.com/support/regional_sett.htm):

[image]

2) use [`Application.DecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207(v=office.15).aspx) in VBA code (e.g. in `Workbook_Open` event):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What about OS X?

Answer (score 5):

My best choice to use the below function which can help to convert the text to numbers also  at the same time. Its very useful in cases where some systme reports are shared with different number formats

=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E3,".",""),",","."))

Comment: Useful formula, but has problems with negative numbers